# Laurent series expansion in a region

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, partial-fractions

Consider the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$$ in the region $2 < |z| < \infty$. I would like to find the partial fraction decomposition and the Laurent series expansion of $f(z) $ in this region.

Partial Fraction Decomposition:
To begin, we need to express $f(z)$ in partial fraction form. We seek constants $A, B, C$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)} = \frac{A}{z}+ \frac{B}{z-1}+ \frac{C}{z-2}$$

And the Laurent series expansion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
{B\over z-1}={Bz^{-1}\over1-z^{-1}}=Bz^{-1}+Bz^{-2}+Bz^{-3}+\dotsb
$$
and
$$
{C\over z-2}={Cz^{-1}\over1-2z^{-1}}=Cz^{-1}+2Cz^{-2}+4Cz^{-3}+\dotsb
$$
so the Laurent series is $(A+B+C)z^{-1}+\sum_2^{\infty}(B+2^{n-1}C)z^{-n}$.

Now, we just have to do the partial fractions part to get $A,B,C$.

Clearing fractions,
$$
1=A(z-1)(z-2)+Bz(z-2)+Cz(z-1)
$$
Substituting in turn $z=0$, $z-1$, $z=2$, we get simple equations for $A,B,C$. The reader is encouraged to carry out the arithmetic.